# How to convert byte array to .csv file in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, csv

How i can convert byte array(send as a string in JSON) to .csv file.

What I have done so far is

Converted the JSON receive as a sting to unit8list

and created a new file with .csv file and writing content as `file.writeAsBytes(bytes)`

I am getting .csv file but the data is written in single-cell(is as string received in received JSON response )

```
// response from json
DownloadResponse  value = DownloadResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(value.object);
   Uint8List bytes8 = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
   print("-------------- List<int> ------------");

   print(bytes);
   print("-------------- END List<int> ------------");

   print("\n\n-------------- List<Unit8> ------------");

   print(bytes8);

   print("\n\n-------------- END List<Unit8> ------------");

print("location supply!!");
   File file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/${currentFile.fileName}');
   File filety = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file2.csv');


   print("creating file");
   var file2 = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
   var file3 = await filety.writeAsBytes(bytes8);

   var parent = file2.parent;
   var parent2 = file2.parent;
   print("parant: $parent");
   print("parant2: $parent2");
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(
   MaterialApp(
     title: 'Reading and Writing Files',
     home: MyApp(),
   ),
 );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<MyApp> {
 String data;
 String byteStr = "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";

 Future<File> moveFile(File sourceFile, String newPath) async {
   try {
     /// prefer using rename as it is probably faster
     /// if same directory path
     return await sourceFile.rename(newPath);
   } catch (e) {
     /// if rename fails, copy the source file
     final newFile = await sourceFile.copy(newPath);
     return newFile;
   }
 }

 Future<String> get _localPath async {
   final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   print(directory.path);
   return directory.path;
 }

 Future<String> dirpath() async {
   var path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
   print("download: "+path);
   return path;
 }

 Future<File> get _localFile async {
   final path = await _localPath;
    final extpath = await dirpath();

   File src = File('$path/counter.txt');
   String desc = '$extpath/counter.txt';

   var status = await Permission.storage.status;
   if (!status.isGranted) {
     await Permission.storage.request();

     var file =  await moveFile(src,desc);
     print("file::: ${file.path}");
   }

   // Permission.storage.request();

   File('$extpath/counter.txt');

   return File('$path/counter.txt');
 }

 Future<String> readContent() async {
   try {
     final file = await _localFile;
     // Read the file
     String contents = await file.readAsString();
     // Returning the contents of the file
     return contents;
   } catch (e) {
     // If encountering an error, return
     return 'Error!';
   }
 }

 Future<File> writeContent() async {
   final file = await _localFile;
   // Write the file
   return file.writeAsString('Hello Folk');
 }

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
    askedPermission();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Reading and Writing data')),
     body: Center(

       child: Column(
         children: [
           Text(
             'Data read from a file: \n $data',
           ),
           SizedBox(height: 20,),
           FlatButton(onPressed: (){
             setState(()  {

                // write();
               writeCsv();

             });
           }, child: Text("write")),

         ],
       ))
   );
 }

 Future<void> askedPermission() async {
   var status = await Permission.storage.status;
   print("start Status $status");
   if (!status.isGranted) {
     await Permission.storage.request();
     status = await Permission.storage.status;

       if(status.isGranted){

         print("location supply!!");
         File file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.text');
         print("creating file");
         var file2 = await file.writeAsString("dhddhhd");

         var parent = file2.parent;
         print("parant: $parent");

        /* writeContent();
         readContent().then((String value) {
           setState(() {
             data = value;
           });
         });*/
       }
       else{
         print("No Permission to write File !!");
       }

   }
   print("end Status $status");
 }

 Future<void> write() async {

   print("location supply!!");
   File file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.text');
   print("creating file");
   var file2 = await file.writeAsString("dhddhhd");

   var parent = file2.parent;
   print("parant: $parent");
 }

 Future<void> writeCsv() async {

   List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(byteStr);
   Uint8List bytes8 = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
   print("-------------- List<int> ------------");

   print(bytes);
   print("-------------- END List<int> ------------");

   print("\n\n-------------- List<Unit8> ------------");

   print(bytes8);

   print("\n\n-------------- END List<Unit8> ------------");

   print("location supply!!");
   File file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.csv');
   File filety = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/file2.csv');

   print("creating file");
   var file2 = await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
   var file3 = await filety.writeAsBytes(bytes8);

   var parent = file2.parent;
   print("parant: $parent");
 }
}
```

Comment: You did not tell what would be in your byte array nor how you wanted the csv file to look like. Further you did not post reproducable code so what do you expect from us? There is not even a byte array in your code.

Comment: updated JSON response @blackapps

Comment: Put the response string in the code. Otherwise we have to do it. Just post code we can copy/paste.

Comment: actually, the server is sending objectType value is the data type.

Comment: You stil did not put that json in a string variable and used that variable in your code. You only added code that we cannot copy/paste.

Comment: updated main.dart file here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228464/discussion-between-hasan-mohd-khan-and-blackapps).

Comment: No chatting. And posting that file makes no sense. You should only make your code copy/paste ready. Like var jsonSting = ".... put your json here...". And then use it like List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(jsonString); or something like that. Copy/paste ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to create a CSV file by just decoding using base64.
Leaving answer here in case anybody needs it.

```
var decode = base64.decode(JsonResponseString);
    var csvStr = utf8.decode(decode);
    print(csvStr.toString());

    print("creating file...");
    File file =
        new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/${currentFile.fileName}.csv');

    file.writeAsString(csvStr);
```